# Camping with a Pure Ruby database

Tags: ruby, camping

I would like to use a pure ruby database (kirbybase http://www.netpromi.com/files/kirbybase_ruby_manual.html ) together with Camping (http://camping.io the ruby microframework) so in ruby we would have something like this to display a record:

```
require 'kirbybase'
db = KirbyBase.new
cars_tbl= db.get_table(:cars)
ferrari = cars_tbl.select { |r| r.recno == 9 }
puts ferrari
```

or for all records

```
results = cars_tbl.select(:name,:race,:color,:recno).sort(+:color)
```

what would be the best way to integrate this with Camping without obfuscating the "rubysh "kirbybase syntax?
A simple module for connecting to an Sqlite (default database on camping) through active record would look like this

module Models
    class Content < Base; end

```
class BasicFields < V 1.0
  def self.up
    create_table Content.table_name do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text   :text
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table Content.table_name
  end      
end
```

end

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Since Camping uses rails' active record, you will need an active record connection adapter for it.

The [ackbar](http://ackbar.rubyforge.org/) gem appears to fill this need.

Comment: ackbar is broken since a long time. I would want to use this without active record. KirbyBase is noSQL and wouldn't work well with ActiveBase.